# Uniform Fourier Series

Tags: linear-algebra, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

> Find the Fourier series of the function which is $8$ on $\left[0, \pi/4\right]$ and
>   zero everywhere else.

We start by noting that this is an even function if we expand the range to [-π/4, π/4], so it has a cosine series.
We get:

$a_0$ = $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

$a_n =\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} 8\cos(nx)\right] = \frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{8}{\pi n}\sin(nx)\vert_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}\right]  = \frac{1}{2} \left[\frac{8}{\pi n}\sin(\frac{\pi}{4}n) + \frac{8}{\pi n}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}n\right) \right].$

I'm confused as to how to move on from here. I think I have the basic gist, but can someone really walk me through it?

Comment: You already have done all the calculations, just notice that $\sin \left( \frac{n\pi}{4} \right)$ is only a function of $n \mod 8$.

Comment: And what does that tell us...

Comment: It is only if you want an "nicer" expression without $\sin$, except that fact your result is the final one, there is no need to "move" from it.

Comment: But I am correct in the notion that the b_k term is 0? And from here, I just need to plug into the normal Fourier expansion?

Comment: It depends of your function.